# How to disable specific days for week view jQuery fullcalendar

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, ajax

Is their a configurable way to visibly disable the specific days in the week view of jQuery fullcalendar?

I have a start date and an end date.Only display the days between start and end date.

> Consider the start date is 1/10/2014 and end date is 7/10/2014, I need
>   to block users to edit days before 1/10/2014 and after 7/10/2014. 
>   Also the disabled days has to be greyed out and unselectable.  I need
>   a visual effect to let the user feel that the specific range are not
>   selectable.

Comment: is this fullcalendar? http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/ If so use the properties visStart-visEnd of View object http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/views/View_Object/

Answer (score 0):

You should use jQuery UI datepicker control

Below code allows you to select dates between May 10th 2014 and May 20th 2014

**jQuery Code**

```
$( "#txtStartDate" ).datepicker({
        minDate: new Date(2014,5-1,10),
        maxDate: new Date(2014,5-1,20)
});
```

As you can see in demo other dates are grayed out.

Refer this [link](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#min-max) for API documentation of jQuery UI datepicker control

Check this [fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/chiragvidani/ZZkc2/2/)

Comment: plz refer this link http://jquery-week-calendar.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/jquery.weekcalendar/full_demo/weekcalendar_full_demo.html

Comment: how to visible only the specified range of days